# Why do I get a blank page after uploading a Laravel project to my remote server?

Tags: laravel-4

After uploading my Laravel project to my remote Linux server that runs Ubuntu LTS 12.04 loading any page is turning back a blank page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case this was caused by incorrect folder permissions on the `app\storage` folder. Change the permissions on this folder to `777` by issuing `chmod -R 777` on the storage folder. Be sure to only do this on the storage folder.

Comment: it's advised to go 775 instead of 777 (without execute permission)

Comment: @zwacky Thanks for your comment I guess your right on that, I will try that and update the answer accordingly!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, in addition to the storage permissions, make sure that all the view files names match, my local host didn't complain about the case but my server threw an exception saying that the view doesn't exist because it was named with a capital letter.